# Parsing two kinds of json with one case class?

Tags: scala, circe

I have a case class in scala that needs to parse a json object.  However the json object can look two different ways.  Like this:

```
 "hint": {
            "structure": [
               "HIDE"
            ]
         }
```

Or like this:

```
"hint": {
          "type": "1",
          "template": "A"
        }
```

I want to parse them both into the same case class in Scala using circe.  I've trie doing something like this:

```
case class Hint(`type`:Option[String] = None,template:Option[String], structure: Option[List[String]])

object Hint {
        implicit val hintJsonDecoder: Decoder[Hint] = deriveDecoder[Hint]
      implicit val hintJsonEncoder: ObjectEncoder[Hint] = deriveEncoder[rHint]

}
```

But it seems like there should be a neater way of doing this so that I can just return say a list of strings in the case of the first instance, and just the type and template in the second instance.  But I can't figure out how to do this using Circe.

Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understand your question, but the use of Option gives you what you wan't. If you wanted a less verbose solution, you can use auto-derivation like as follows:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser.decode

case class HintContainer(hint: Hint)
case class Hint(`type`: Option[String], template: Option[String], structure: Option[List[String]])

object Sample extends App {
  val testData1 =
    """
      |{
      | "hint": {
      |     "structure": [
      |         "HIDE"
      |     ]
      | }
      |}
      |""".stripMargin

  val testData2 =
    """
      |{
      | "hint": {
      |     "type": "1",
      |     "template": "A"
      | }
      |}
      |""".stripMargin

  println(decode[HintContainer](testData1))
  println(decode[HintContainer](testData2))

}
```

Which gives:

```
Right(HintContainer(Hint(None,None,Some(List(HIDE)))))
Right(HintContainer(Hint(Some(1),Some(A),None)))
```